# How to store state of disable button(s) even after refreshing a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons on my page. If a user clicks one, the other gets disabled and vice versa. Suppose if, **'Button1'** was enabled. This means that **'Button2'** gets disabled. And now, when I click on 'Button 2'.... **'Button1' gets disabled**. **However, when I refresh the page, 'Button1' gets enabled and 'Button2' gets disabled again**. How can I store the state of the last disabled button and view it after refreshing the page?

This is what I tried so far:

**template.html:**

```
<button type="button" id ='button1'> Button 1 </button> 
<br> <br>
<button type="button" id ='button2' disabled /> Button 2 </button>
```

**template.js (using Jquery):**

```
    $('#button1').click(function () {
        $("#button1").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);

    $('#button2').click(function () {
        $("#button2").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#button1").attr("disabled", false);
```

How can I store the last state of the disabled button after refreshing the page?

Comment: You can use localStorage/sessionStorage, cookies or a server side data store (accessed through AJAX) to hold state. Which is best for your case depends on how long you want state held for, and how secure it needs to be

Comment: store the values into browser localstorage and load it from there

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you for your reply. I am new to JS/jQuery so is it okay to ask for a small demonstration, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store the state in [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and use that on page load to set the attribute:

[**`localStorage`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a Storage object for the Document's origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions. `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except that while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

```
var disbledBtn = localStorage.getItem('disabled'); // get the id from localStorage
$(disbledBtn).attr("disabled", true); // set the attribute by the id

$('#button1').click(function () {
  $("#button1").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#button2").attr("disabled", false);
  localStorage.setItem('disabled', '#button1'); // store the id in localStorage
  ......
});
$('#button2').click(function () {
  $("#button2").attr("disabled", true);
  $("#button1").attr("disabled", false);
  localStorage.setItem('disabled', '#button2'); // store the id in localStorage
  .....
});
```

Comment: whats the difference between sessionstorage and localstorage?

Comment: @danny_boy, data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends:)

Comment: @danny_boy localStorage is a storage per domain, sessionStorage is a storage per session. If you open your app in two different tabs, for example, you can share data through localStorage, but their sessionStorage will be private for each of them.

Comment: Your solution is the one I am searching for. Can you explain what you had done?

Comment: @danny_boy after you decide which to use (`sessionStorage` or `localStorage`), which should depend on your needs (you want the state of the button to stay even after you close the tab and open it the day after? or just in case of refresh?) you should keep the state of the button in them each time it is changed (`sessionStorage.setItem('buttonState', state)`). When loading the page, read the state from the saved data (`sessionStorage.getItem('buttonState')`) and change the state of the button accordingly.